# Which book were the Pegataur Ranger rules in?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

I remember from many years ago, I had a pegataur ranger in a DnD campaign. I can't remember which version of D&D it was from, or which book it was from. Any ideas?

I do remember that the book had a brown cover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no specific rules for playing pegataur rangers in any edition of D&D prior to 3rd edition. (In 3rd edition the pegataur is a playable race simply by virtue of generic monstrous characters rules, and there are no special pegataur/ranger rules.) However, the "brown cover" is a dead giveaway for an AD&D 2nd edition campaign using one of the "Complete" handbooks.

Despite there being no *specific* rules for pegataur rangers, I think I've figured out what you're remembering. What your DM likely did was use the loose recommendations in the *[Complete Book of Humanoids](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/49892/the-complete-book-of-humanoids)* (pp. 15-16) to create a playable race from the pegataur monster entry in the *[Monstrous Compendium, Mystara Appendix](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/50366/monstrous-compendium-mystara-appendix)* (p. 86), and then used the "Wilderness Protector" fighter kit in the *Complete Book of Humanoids* (p. 72) to create a ranger-equivalent fighter-based class for your character. This kind of *ad hoc* character-creation rules based on loose recommendations and GM permission was common in AD&D 2nd edition, so it's no stretch at all to figure that this is how your past pegataur PC came to be.

Prior to AD&D, the only appearance of pegataurs a player-character race is in [Top Ballista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Ballista) (1989), which describes a flying gnomish city as a campaign setting/expansion in the Mystara world. However, since this is a *Basic Dungeons & Dragons* book, PC pegataurs advance with a race-as-class paradigm and aren't able to be a separate class like ranger as well.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely answer is [The Complete Book of Humanoids](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560766115) for AD&D's Second Edition. It's brown, and has the rules for centaur characters, which would probably include variants like the pegataur.

Comment: That is definitely the book, the reviews sound spot on!  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just looked inside, and it appears to not be the right book.   But it's helping me narrow it down.  It's definitely from that series / addition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still continuing my research, but what I'm finding is that pegataurs appeared in the following AD&D/2e books...

- Module M2: Vengeance of Alphaks by Skip Williams,
- AC9: Creature Catalogue
- Mystara Monstrous Compendium Appendix.

But that's just the creature.  I imagine that your ranger just focused on them as a monster and there's not a random specifically dedicated class.

Comment: There were rules to make a Pegatuar a PC, and I remember it getting racial bonuses that meshed with a ranger.